# Get method in which PsiMethodCallExpression is used

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

Currently I'm writing a code inspection in which I need to identify certain methods usages. For this purpose I'm using `visitCallExpression(expression: PsiCallExpression)` and it works fine. However I need to understand in which method `PsiCallExpression` was called in order to skip inspection in certain cases. For example I want my inspection to be skipped in test classes and some specific methods. I already tried using `getUseScope`, but it's completely unclear how to proceed with the result and get fully qualified method name from it.

Comment: I'd recommend you raise this issue at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200366979-IntelliJ-IDEA-Open-API-and-Plugin-Development to discuss it with the IDEA team directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually it was answered at intelij support: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/11522817858834-Get-method-in-which-PsiMethodCallExpression-is-used
All in all there is no trivial way to do this, but it's possible to iterate through the elements in the elements tree till you find `PsiMethod` and in general this should be it.
Here is the code snippet which does the trick:

```
var element = expression.getParent()
while (element != null) {
    if (element is PsiMethod) {
        val method = element as PsiMethod
        // do whatever you want to do with PsiMethod instance
    } else {
        element = element.getParent()
    }
}
```